# NodeJS errno 37 on socket.connect

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm trying to connect to multiple hosts in succession, this is the code to resolve the ip address and socket.connect() to each domain name (line[1]). This works on it's own but returns an errno 37 error when run in quick succession with different hosts. The best information I have on the error is:

" code: 'EPROTO', description: 'protocol error' "

Code:

```
$.connect(port, line[1], function() {
  this.write(request);   
});
```

Error:

```
{ [Error: connect Unknown system errno 37]
  code: 'Unknown system errno 37',
  errno: 'Unknown system errno 37',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

How can I resolve this / why is this happening?

Comment: What is `$.connect`? If it is `net.connect`, why are you doing the DNS lookup? It will do it for you.

Comment: haha thanks, it's socket.connect but as i've just found out it works the same way :) EDIT: issue still persists though

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Is this coming back from `resolve`, or  `connect`?

Comment: this is the error: { [Error: connect Unknown system errno 37]
  code: 'Unknown system errno 37',
  errno: 'Unknown system errno 37',
  syscall: 'connect' }

Comment: It sometimes works with one or two hosts, sometimes crashes

Comment: Just experienced the same error thrown using the node-amqp lib, only seeing this happen on reconnecting to the queues ... anyone know what errno 37 actually means ?

Comment: I have same issue, and cannot nail it down.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672743/nodejs-crash-when-calling-socket-connect-in-quick-succession

Seems to me opening sockets in rapid succession is asking for trouble.

Try waiting in between opening the sockets and play with the amount of time needed to wait.